# Why I'm getting duplicated results?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a code which will list even numbers from the array and then print sum of odd numbers:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {4, 643, 112, 9999, 69};
    int sumOdd = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        if (numbers[j] % 2 != 0) {
            sumOdd = sumOdd + numbers[j];
        }
        System.out.println("SUMA " + sumOdd);
    }
}
```

But my results are as follow:

```
4
112
SUMA 0
SUMA 643
SUMA 643
SUMA 10642
SUMA 10711
```

Can you point what's wrong so I can have result:

```
4
112
SUMA 10711
```

(all in separate lines)

Comment: Move `System.out.println("SUMA " + sumOdd);` outside the loop

Comment: Don't use two loops. If a value is even then the other is obviously odd. Use **if/else**: `if (this is even) { Display it; } else { sum+= numbers[i]; }`

Answer (score 0):

Justo move the  `System.out.println("SUMA " + sumOdd);` out of the for loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {4, 643, 112, 9999, 69};
        int sumOdd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(numbers[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            if (numbers[j] % 2 != 0) {
                sumOdd = sumOdd + numbers[j];
            }

            }
        System.out.println("SUMA " + sumOdd);
    }
```

As said in the comments you can also skip the second for loop by adding an else statement like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 4, 643, 112, 9999, 69 };
    int sumOdd = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        } else {
            sumOdd = sumOdd + numbers[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("SUMA " + sumOdd);
}
```